# Laravel route is not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing this error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Route [projects.adduser] not defined. (View: E:\wamp64\www\pmanagement\resources\views\projects\show.blade.php)

My route is defined in the HTML below:

```
<form id="add-user" action="{{  route('projects.adduser',[$project->id])  }}" method="POST">
```

and this is my route code:

```
Route::post('projects/adduser/{project_id?}','ProjectsController@adduser');
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to name the route:

```
Route::post('projects/adduser/{project_id?}', 'ProjectsController@adduser')->name('projects.adduser');
```

Or you could use the `url()` helper instead of `route()`:

```
url('projects/adduser/' . $project->id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your route to use it like that, for example:

```
 Route::post('projects/adduser/{project_id?}')
    ->uses('ProjectsController@adduser')
    ->name('projects.adduser');
```

Named routes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes

Comment: No, route('') uses the name of the route

Comment: Personally, I would always name routes, because if, in the future, you decide to overhaul your urls, let's say for SEO purposes, you won't need to change your code, because it'll be using the named routes, rather than the actual URL... As mentioned by Alexey, you can also use the URL class: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php